# Should [adb-shell] be a synonym for [adb]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

There are only 25 questions currently tagged with [adb-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adb-shell) and 16 of them have both [adb-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adb-shell) and [adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adb) tags.

There are about 4000 of `adb` questions and my conservative estimation is that well over 50% of those are related to the shell sub-command of `adb`.

Does the `adb-shell` deserve to be a separate tag?